# How to set RabbitMQ queue prefix when using CAP

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq

We're using [dotnetcore/CAP](https://github.com/dotnetcore/CAP) with RabbitMQ. I've followed the same setup as our other CAP code, but for some reason I'm getting "cap.queue" prefix on my queue name.

All of our other queues are named like this:

> [NameInAppSettings].v1

For some reason, my new queue is like this:

> cap.queue.[NameInAppSettings].v1

The default group is set like this:

```
services.AddCap(options =>
{
    options.DefaultGroup = Configuration["SubscriptionClientName"];
}
```

I've confirmed that the appsettings setting exists and we're hitting the above line of code. Before the above line executes, `options.DefaultGroup` has the "cap.queue" prefix. After that line executes, it's just "[NameInAppSettings].v1". So why does the queue name, when looking in the RMQ dashboard, have the "cap.queue" prefix? Where can I set that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there are two settings that control this behavior.

First, `DefaultGroup` does need to be set.
Second, `ExchangeName` also needs to be set.

These values simply need to exist. If they're missing, then default exchanges/queues will be created.

Both of those are shown here:

```
    services.AddCap(x =>
    {
        // other settings here

        x.DefaultGroup = "Sandbox";
        
        x.UseRabbitMQ(conf =>
        {
            conf.ExchangeName = "SandboxEventBus";
            conf.ConnectionFactoryOptions = x =>
            {
                x.Uri = BuildRabbitUri();
            };
        });
    });
```

For completeness, here is `BuildRabbitUri()`:

```
    public static Uri BuildRabbitUri()
    {
        string protocol = "amqp";
        string userName = "guest";
        string password = "guest";
        string host = "localhost";
        string port = "6003";

        return new Uri(protocol + "://" + userName + ":" + password + "@" + host + ":" + port);
    }
```